# How to programmatically unset mysqli object?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some scripts that I want to unset the variables of at the end. This is the code I'm using the programmatically unset them all:

```
function xyz() {
    $list_of_vars =  array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $GLOBALS);
    foreach($list_of_vars as $var){
        unset($var);
    }
    unset($list_of_vars);
}
```

The problem is, some of my variables include mysqli objects, so the above code throws the following error:

```
Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string
```

How do I modify the code so that it works with mysqli objects as well as all the other variables I have?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: which line is causing error?

Comment: Why are you doing this? PHP cleans up at the end of the script execution already

Comment: @nbin: The second line. @ Phil: To force cleaning up for memory. @ ehwas: Hmmm? I'm already closing the connection. I need a way to close / unset all variables but the above code also pulls in mysqli object.

Comment: So it is not an unset issue I guess. Is your $list_of_vars doing fine?

Comment: @nbin: I believe the issue is the second line is putting all variables into an array, and you can't put mysqli object into an array. I need some code that finds mysqli objects from the results provided by get_defined_vars and unsets them individually as opposed to putting them in an array.

Comment: you can use is_object with to check for object and unset it. no?

Comment: @nbin: But how would that work if I can't output the variables via get_defined_vars into an array to check for with is_object?